# Find the number of solutions to a congruence equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

> Problem: Find the number of solutions to the congruence equation $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{280}$.

Attempt: Since $280 = 2^3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$, we know $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{280} \iff x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{2^3}, x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$. I think we can say something about the number of solutions to each of the congruence equations using the fact that there exist primitive roots for $2^3, 5$ and $7$ respectively. However, I am not sure how the argument would go exactly... any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes I do know the theorem.

Comment: Well by the Chinese remainder theorem, if you have a set of solutions to the 3 congruences, it gives rise to exactly one solution mod $280$.

Comment: Yes that's what I did in the "Attempt" section. What I am trying to figure out is how many solutions I have for, for example, $x^3 \equiv 1 \pmod{5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, $$x^3\equiv 1\pmod{280}\implies x^3\equiv 1\pmod k, k=5,7,8$$

We find by trial that

$x^3\equiv 1\pmod 8$ has $4$ solutions

$x^3\equiv 1\pmod 5$ has $1$ solution

$x^3\equiv 1\pmod 7$ has $3$ solutions

By the Chinese remainder theorem, each combination of these solutions gives rise to a unique solution modulo 280, so there are $4\cdot1\cdot3=12$ solutions.

Comment: For a systematic general solution, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2720157/300700